# Looking for DUAL slideshow/carousel options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, carousel

A client wants to share slides from a presentation on their site, but with a matching set of "annotations" alongside, essentially requiring a double, synchronized slideshow. I've only managed to find a single jQuery plugin, [dualSlider](http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/index.html), which does this. That seems suspicious so I wondered if I might just be missing other options due to naming, description, etc. Is anyone aware of others?

- jQuery is preferred but not an absolute requirement.
- Both panes should accept arbitrary content.
- The ability to pull directly from Flickr galleries would make everyone very happy, but I realize this is uncommon.
- I'm aware each set of slides could be composited into a single image file, etc. Trying to avoid that for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most single sliders offer a way to control the sliders.

For example, the jQuery cycle plugin (See: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), can easily be accomplished  by creating two lists, giving them the same timings and speed, and create your buttons like this:

```
<div id="gallery1">... slideshow images/divs here</div>
<div id="gallery1">... second slideshow images/divs here</div>
<div id="nextbutton">
   Next
</div>
```

And in js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gallery1").cycle();
    $("#gallery2").cycle();

    $("#nextbutton").click(function () { 
        $("#gallery1").cycle('next');
        $("#gallery2").cycle('next');
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, duh. In wanting to be lazy and hunting something pre-packaged, I hadn't even considered the APIs some of these offer. This'll also give me some more styling freedom over picking up a new one, as there are a few I've already worked with and styled in the past.